# How do I count multiple words available in sentences and multiple rows (countif, search)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, countif

here is screenshot for the sheet.
https://flic.kr/p/qZb8ot

in column A there are some senteces list below:

- A2. T-shirts, Varsity
- A3. T-shirts, Sticker, Mug
- A4. T-shirts
- A5. T-shirts, Pin, Varsity, Mug
- A6. Sticker,Pin, Hat, Mug
- A7. Pin,Varsity, Bracelet
- A8. T-shirts, Pin, Varsity, Mug
- A9. T-shirts Hat
- A10. T-shirts, Varsity
- A11. T-shirts, Sticker, Pin, Varsity, Mug, Bracelet
- A12. T-shirts, Sticker
- A13. T-shirts, Sticker,Pin, Mug
- ...
- ..
- ...
- A44. Varsity

i would like to count a occurrence a word in sentences and multiple row.
the range is about `A2:A44`

and i want to count a word that in `D14` until `D20` for every keyword in `C14` to `D20`...

```
        C         D

      Type      count
14   T-shirts     0
15   Varsity      0
16   Sticker      0
17     Mug        0
18     Pin        0
19   Bracelet     0
20    Other       0
```

I've tried to use `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$44, SEARCH("T-shirts", A2))` for cell D14. it didn't work.
I also tried to use `=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$44, SEARCH("T-shirts", A2)>0)` it didn't work neither.

how to count the type for those words.

separator for every keyword is `,`. 
is there any alternative way to count those words?

any help would appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a wildcard to the `COUNTIF` criteria.

[image: COUNTIF with wildcard]

The formula in D2 is,

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$44, "*"&C2&"*")`

Fill down as necessary. If you prefer something a little different that a `SUM` of those values, the total can also be retrieved with the formula used in D10.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A$2:A$44, "*"&C2:C8&"*"))`

The method you were attempting might be something like this in D2,

`=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2, A$2:A$44)))`